# React Link framer motion animation with AnimatePresence

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I have a Navigation component in which the Menu Items float in separately on load and float out on click.
When I added Router and changed the items to Links, the exit animation didn't work because it loaded the new Route component right away.

**I want to keep the items individual animation with Link functionality.**

**Here is the link:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-leaf-fxsswo?file=/src/components/Navigation.js

Code:

```
export const Navigation = () => {
  const navRef = useRef(null);

  const onResize = () => {
    setIsColumn(window.innerWidth <= 715);
  };

  const [clickOnMenu, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [itemtransition, setTransition] = useState(
    Array(menuItems.length).fill(0)
  );
  const [isColumn, setIsColumn] = useState(window.innerWidth <= 715);

  const click = (e) => {
    const copy = [...itemtransition];
    const index = e.target.id;
    setTransition(copy.map((e, i) => (Math.abs(index - i) + 1) / 10));
    setTimeout(() => setClick(true), 50);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      {!clickOnMenu && (
        <Nav ref={navRef}>
          {menuItems.map((e, i) => {
            const text = Object.keys(e)[0];
            const value = Object.values(e)[0];
            return (
              <Item
                id={i}
                key={value}
                animate={{
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0,
                  opacity: 1,
                  transition: { delay: (i + 1) / 10 }
                }}
                initial={{
                  x: isColumn ? 1000 : 0,
                  y: isColumn ? 0 : 1000,
                  opacity: 0
                }}
                exit={{
                  x: isColumn ? -1000 : 0,
                  y: isColumn ? 0 : -1000,
                  opacity: 0,
                  transition: { delay: itemtransition[i] }
                }}
                onClick={click}
              >
                {/*<Link to={`/${value}`}>{text}</Link>*/}
                {text}
              </Item>
            );
          })}
        </Nav>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

**In the sandbox in Navigation.js 69-70. row:**

**This is the desired animation.**

```
69. {/*<Link to={`/${value}`}>{text}</Link>*/}
70. {text}
```

**But when I use Link there is no exit animation**

```
69. <Link to={`/${value}`}>{text}</Link>
70. {/*text*/}
```

Is there a workaround or I should forget router-dom.

Thank you in forward!

Comment: The code in the sandbox appears to do what you want, but the links don't appear to link to anything, the URL doesn't update. Please edit your post to include a [mcve] ***in the post*** for what you are trying to accomplish and provide clearer details about any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit hackish, but with routing and transitions sometimes that is the nature. I suggest rendering the `Link` so the semantic HTML is correct and add an `onClick` handler to prevent the default navigation action from occurring. This allows any transitions/animations to go through. Then update the `click` handler of the `Item` component to consume the link target and issue an imperative navigation action on a timeout to allow transitions/animations to complete.

I used a 750ms timeout but you may need to tune this value to better suit your needs.

Example:

```
...
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

export const Navigation = () => {
  const navRef = useRef(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- access navigate function

  ...

  const click = target => (e) => { // <-- consume target
    const copy = [...itemtransition];
    const index = e.target.id;
    setTransition(copy.map((e, i) => (Math.abs(index - i) + 1) / 10));
    setTimeout(() => {
      setClick(true);
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate(target); // <-- navigate after some delta
    }, 750);
  };

  ...

  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      {!clickOnMenu && (
        <Nav ref={navRef}>
          {menuItems.map((e, i) => {
            const text = Object.keys(e)[0];
            const value = Object.values(e)[0];
            return (
              <Item
                ...
                onClick={click(`/${value}`)} // <-- pass target to handler
              >
                <Link
                  to={`/${value}`}
                  onClick={e => e.preventDefault()} // <-- prevent link click
                >
                  {text}
                </Link>
              </Item>
            );
          })}
        </Nav>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

...
```

[image: Edit react-link-framer-motion-animation-with-animatepresence]